# Ошибка: метод не определен в классе

Tags: java

Есть два Java файла с одного пакета. При при использование метода выдает ошибку "The method Print(String) is undefined for the type Hello". Подскажите в чем ошибка.

ФАИЛ С МАЙНОМ.

```
package progect1;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Print("a");

    }   
}
```

ФАИЛ С МЕТОДОМ

```
package progect1;

public class Metodi {

    public static void Print(String a) {
        System.out.print(a)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Metodi.Print("a");
}
```